# Why wouldn't router enable LAN ports when connected to another router?

Tags: networking, lan

Apologies if I can't formulate question really well. I have some other routers/APs that I connect via ethernet.

Whenever power goes out I have to go unplug the cable and I need to randomly keep plugging those back. Normal clients like IPTV and a PC connect instantly.

Two ports (3 and 4) are configured to use different VLAN for IPTV.

The wireless extender that I use for another IPTV client won't even register ethernet is connected. To get it going I need to unplug it from IPTV port, plug into port 1, wait a little, then plug back into port 3 all before IPTV box fails it's boot. I've never observed such behaviour - is there some sort of new security feature that routers nowadays ship with?

Router in question is Asus RT-AX92U.

Comment: Have you tried a different cable?

Comment: I did multiple, all comes down whether I connect lan to router or client.